# Enable browser caching for static resources

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, http, iis

To improve the site performance, I'm adding following http headers in IIS 7.5.

```
Expires: Sun, 29 Mar 2020 00:00:00 GMT
```

and

```
Cache-Control: Public
```

I'm adding these headers for `images` folder in site's virtual directory.
When I access the site, I see that for each image present in this folder; those response headers were:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store,Public
Content-Length:4445
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Fri, 06 Jun 2014 09:18:36 GMT
ETag:"16874c2af55ecf1:0"
Expires:-1,Sun, 29 Mar 2020 00:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified:Wed, 23 Apr 2014 13:08:48 GMT
max-age:604800
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

I need browser to take these images from its cache instead of requesting again from server. How should I achieve it?

Comment: Somehow you use the `ETag` find what is place it and disable it for the images.

Comment: @Aristos, I removed `ETag` using solution provided by `KristoferG` at http://forums.iis.net/t/1177192.aspx. But still it is not getting cached.

Comment: See also this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393649/configuring-etags-with-http-module-in-asp-net/11393932#11393932  if this not work then check if your images pass from some kind of http handler that add the no-cache. Also check if you send them via secure protocol, this can make them not been cached.

Comment: The site is configured as `https`. Can this produce a problem?

Comment: Yes probably this is the reason, but I do not have a fast answer on that, other than use the `ETag` that is only make a one trip round to the server and if the ETag has no change the image is not loading again, for this session.

Comment: try this alternative- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22888/Caching-Images-in-ASP-NET

Comment: The other alternative would be using CDN for static data, if you have your own server then simply allocate another domain or a sub-domain, set a new site in IIS and you don't even need to relocate your static resources just change your static urls to the new domain and done. if you don't own a server then just use one of the external CDN which are fast and reliable.

Comment: The `Expires` header has an invalid `HTTP-date`. This indicates that the response has already expired. Remove the "-1," at the front.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your header shows that you add a new value but you need to replace the existing one

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store,Public
Expires:-1,Sun, 29 Mar 2020 00:00:00 GMT
```

`no-cache, no-store` stands for no cache and `-1` says that the content is already expired.

Instead of doing it from the code you can easily set it in the root web.config file as

```
  <location path="images">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseExpires" 
                     httpExpires="Sun, 29 Mar 2020 00:00:00 GMT" /> 
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

where images is a name of your directory

or add dedicated web.config file directly in the target directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseExpires" 
                   httpExpires="Sun, 29 Mar 2020 00:00:00 GMT" /> 
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You can also use cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" and set specific time of expiration

Example to set expiration in 7 days

```
<clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" 
             cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
```

Read more http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689443.aspx